# Using `\headlesscite` with `biblatex-chicago`: how to keep ibids lower-case

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, chicago-style

I format my bibliography with `biblatex-chicago`. I have been using the `ibid` option so when two consecutive citations are to the same work, the second one is typeset as "ibid." followed by the page number. It should be uppercase (Ibid.) when at the beginning of a sentence and lowercase (ibid.) anywhere else. When using `\headlesscite`, however, the result is always "Ibid." -- uppercase.

For example:

```
See \cite[10]{smith:title}.
Smith argues
\parentext{\headlesscite[12]{smith:title}}
that...
```

produces

> See John Smith, *Title of the Book* (Address: Publisher, 2015): 10. Smith argues (Ibid., 12) that...

instead of

> See John Smith, *Title of the Book* (Address: Publisher, 2015): 10. Smith argues (ibid., 12) that...

It's a subtle difference. Is it possible to make this change?

Comment: Why aren't you just writing `\parentext{\cite[12]{smith:title}}`?  And, please, for this and future questions, please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  It is extremely tedious (and very often error-prone) to have to 'reverse engineer' an example file to test with.

Comment: This seems to be status by design. If you want to override this behaviour try `\renewbibmacro*{hlcprenote}{\usebibmacro{hlprenote}}`. Note that instead of `\parentext{\headlesscite[12]{smith:title}}` you will want to use `\headlessparencite[12]{smith:title}`.

Comment: I just noted that my hasty attempt above sometimes produces different output from your expectation and a slightly more sophisticated approach might be in order. Did the above work or are you more interested in a different approach?

Comment: Thank you @moewe, the solution you proposed does the trick! (I continued using `\parentext{\headlesscite[12]{smith:title}}`; is that not equivalent to `\headlessparencite[12]{smith:title}`?) As for your more recent comment, what is different about the output? (As far as I could tell, your solution produced precisely what I wanted.) Does it have a side-effect that I may not have noticed? If not, I would say this is the answer to my question.

Comment: @jon, thank you for the feedback; I'll plan to include a minimal example in future questions.

Comment: My original idea had trouble with prenotes (there was no space after the prenotes). AFAIK `\parentext{\headlesscite[12]{smith:title}}` and `\headlessparencite[12]{smith:title}` should give the same output, the latter is much more idiomatic, though, and shorter. (I rarely see people use `\parentext` directly in the actual document text, normally it is hidden within a high-level macro such as `\headlessparencite`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My earlier suggestion in the comments would not work properly with prenotes, so this one liner has to be extended to do what it we want it to do.

```
\renewbibmacro*{hlcprenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}%
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
      \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifciteseen}
        or
        togl {cms@allshort}
      }
      {\addspace}%
      {\nopunct}}}
```

This is actually the definition of `hlcprenote` in `chicago-notes.cbx` with one crucial difference: We dropped a `\bibsentence` thus disabling the auto-capitalisation.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{hlcprenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}%
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
      \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifciteseen}
        or
        togl {cms@allshort}
      }
      {\addspace}%
      {\nopunct}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{worman} and \headlessparencite[12]{worman} or \cite{worman} and \headlessparencite[cf][12]{worman}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thank you for this answer, which works perfectly in my document. It occurs to me that occasionally one wishes to be able to capitalize "ibid." when it appears at the beginning of a sentence (usually when used at the beginning of a footnote). Would it be possible to create a command `\Headlesscite` by analogy with `\Cite` and `\Volcite` which would capitalize in the event that an "ibid." is used? (Also: should I mark this question as answered and pose my new question about keeping it capitalized in another question? Or should I keep these related inquiries together?)

Comment: @AlexRoberts Of course, I would like to answer two questions `;-)`. But since it is only one line that would probably be overkill. (In general though it is better to separate follow-up questions especially if the original question has been answered in good faith.) Here you go `\newrobustcmd*{\Headlesscite}{\bibsentence\headlesscite}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll make sure to separate my follow-up question next time. I really appreciate your help as I prepare to submit my dissertation.

Comment: @AlexRoberts No worries! Good luck with your dissertation.